# Change class on a children div with jquery

Tags: jquery

Good morning,
I’trying to change the class of a specific children div, identified by its class. The script should works on document load.

Example:

```
<div class=“test1”>
     <div class=“bravo”> </div>
</div>

<div class=“test2”>
     <div class=“bravo”> </div>
</div>

<div class=“test3”>
     <div class=“bravo”> </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the “bravo” class in “alpha” only for the children div with the class “test2”.

I need it in jquery, on document load.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try adding what you've tried so far.

Comment: Try starting with those two links: [Running code on content load with JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and [Removing Class with JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). After reading and trying something, come back with your doubts (if you have any left) and show us what you've tried. I'll gladly help you

Answer (score 1):

When the document is ready and loaded, you can target using child reference and `$.toggleClass()`. Also, you have got your quotes wrong. Don't use `“”` but use `""`:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".test2 .bravo").toggleClass("alpha bravo");
});
```

```css
.bravo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.alpha {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="test3">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>
```

You can also use child selector this way if you have nested `bravo` classes:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".test2 > .bravo").toggleClass("alpha bravo");
});
```

```css
.bravo {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}

.alpha {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>

<div class="test3">
  <div class="bravo"> </div>
</div>
```

> * I have used some margin, padding and background colours for better representation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($){
$('.test2 .bravo').addClass('alpha').removeClass('bravo');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
     <div class="bravo">a </div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
     <div class="bravo"> b</div>
</div>

<div class="test3">
     <div class="bravo">c </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why no explanation?